# textbox overlap on label in Razor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a form in that form , `Publish_Date_From` field and `Publish_Date_To` field text boxes overlap on their labels

like following picture

[image]

this is the relevant code snippet to above section

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD", maxlength = "50" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publish_Date_From, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_To, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publish_Date_To, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD", maxlength = "50" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publish_Date_To, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>            
         </div>
</div>
```

how to align them properly ?

Comment: This is because your text is too big to fit in col-md-2, better you split your word

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I havent used `col-md-2`  class is it ?

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

Comment: Try with col-md-4 for label and col-md-8 for textbox

Comment: once with `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })` [show like this](http://i.imgur.com/pStI47k.jpg) , how to align text box at end of the label in same row ?

Comment: your use of classes is too bad.Including `col-md-* ` in `col-xs-*`.Try to use `col-xs-*` if you are displaying on mobile devices

Comment: @Hazard are you saying  use `col-xs-*` instead of `col-md-*`

Comment: For which kind of devices you need that view ?

Comment: just want to show desktop , no need to responsive view

Comment: go through [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) without `col-*-*` as you don't need responsive.Far better than struggling with `col-*-*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-xs-6" })
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD", maxlength = "50" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publish_Date_From, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_To, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-xs-6" })
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publish_Date_To, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD", maxlength = "50" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publish_Date_To, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>            
     </div>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
   </div>            
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publish_Date_From, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "YYYY/MM/DD", maxlength = "50" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publish_Date_From, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```